# Facebook app appoval for a live app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a live Facebook app that is currently used in a production website. This app has not been submitted for approval as it does not need any extended permissions.

With the upcoming feature, the app will require access to an extended permission (manage_pages). Thus I will have to submit the app to Facebook for review.

As I understand the steps to recreate the user experience has to be mentioned when submitting for review. My problem is that the new feature is not available in production until the Facebook review is complete. How will the app approval process happen as I need to list out the steps to test the app when submitting?

As an alternative I could put the app back to sandbox mode and send the review, but that would disrupt the already exiting feature (which requires the app to be live).

Is there an alternate way that I could get the app approved without having to disable any existing features?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add a test app, and enable your app to use that when in dev mode.

Comment: Yes, I already do that. However, as I understand the app that is used in production is the one that has to be submitted for review. Since the live app is not yet approved, the feature is not in production. The feature is not in production because the app the is not approved. Therefore how will the app approval process happen since the feature is not in production ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out, there is currently no way, that Facebook helps you with this.

Have you found out something?

I opened an issue in the facebook-bug-tracker:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1594700337461753/

**Edit:**
As Facebook mentions in this bug-report, the best way for this is to mention the app-id and domain of the pre-production app to the reviewer.